# Codeigniter: You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, api

I am trying to insert data using a submitted form. Data is entered properly in the database, but I'm doing API also for mobile. If `is_api` parameter is received, I'm doing `jsone_encode`. The following is the code:

**Controller:**

```
public function send_request(){
            if($this->input->post('submit')){        
                $user_data['data'] = array( 
                    'user_id'                =>  1,
                    'sender_name'            =>     $this->input->post('sender_name'),
                    'sender_location'        =>     $this->input->post('sender_location'),
                    'sender_mobile'          =>     $this->input->post('sender_mobile'),
                    'receiver_name'          =>     $this->input->post('reciever_name'),
                    'receiver_location'      =>     $this->input->post('reciver_location'),
                    'receiver_mobile'        =>     $this->input->post('reciver_location'),
                    'request_type'           =>     $this->input->post('request_type'),
                    'is_urget'              =>     0,
                );

            }
            $result = $this->user_model->send_request($user_data);
             if($result){
                $this->result_set['message'] = 'Data entered ';
                $this->result_set['status']= 1;
             }
                if( $this->input->post('is_api') == 1){
                    echo json_encode($this->result_set);
                    die();
                }
         }
```

**Model:**

```
public function send_request($data){
        $this->db->insert('parcel_requests',$data['data']);
        return true;
     }
```

When I check `hurl.it` for API, I get this error and response:

> ## A Database Error Occurred
>
> You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
>
> Filename: /home/foldername/public_html/parcel/models/user_model.php
>
> Line Number: 21

This is line number 21:

```
    $this->db->insert('parcel_requests',$data['data']);
```

Now data is entered properly, but *not converted to json*. I need your help to sort out this issue, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried  to just pass only the $data array to the insert function instead of $data['data']?

Comment: Check your query string with `$sql = $this->db->set($data['data'])->get_compiled_insert('parcel_requests');
echo $sql;`

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
public function send_request(){
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $user_data['data'] = array(
            'user_id'                =>  1,
            'sender_name'            =>     $this->input->post('sender_name'),
            'sender_location'        =>     $this->input->post('sender_location'),
            'sender_mobile'          =>     $this->input->post('sender_mobile'),
            'receiver_name'          =>     $this->input->post('reciever_name'),
            'receiver_location'      =>     $this->input->post('reciver_location'),
            'receiver_mobile'        =>     $this->input->post('reciver_location'),
            'request_type'           =>     $this->input->post('request_type'),
            'is_urget'              =>     0,
        );
        // inside your if ;), you should insert to database only if you submit data... 

        $result = $this->user_model->send_request($user_data);
        if($result){
            $this->result_set['message'] = 'Data entered ';
            $this->result_set['status']= 1;
        }
        if( $this->input->post('is_api') == 1){
            echo json_encode($this->result_set);
            die();
        }
    } else {
        print 'nthg sumbited';
    }
 }

public function send_request($data){
    $this->db->insert('parcel_requests',$data['data']);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1;
    // Will return true after insert will be ended with success
}
```

In your version there was possibility to send empty array :) and thats why this exception shows :)

Answer (score 0):

change your `$user_data['data'] = array` to `$data['data'] = array`